# How to remove default form tag while rendering output in hook_theme

Tags: php, html, drupal-7, hook-theme

I am customizing the login form. I have to put all the three forms(login, register, forgotpassword) into one page. This is my code.

**template.php**

```
function bartik_theme() {

    $items = array();

    $items['user_login'] = array(
        'render element' => 'div',
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'variables' => array('form' => NULL),
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'user-login',
        'preprocess functions' => array(
            'bartik_preprocess_user_login'
        ),
   );

    return $items;
}
```

**user-login.tpl.php**

```
<div id="signupbox">

  <?php

    $login_form = drupal_get_form ( 'user_login_block' );
    echo drupal_render ( $login_form );

    $forgot_password_form = drupal_get_form ( 'user_pass' );
    echo drupal_render ( $forgot_password_form );

    $register_form = drupal_get_form ( 'user_register_form' );
    echo drupal_render ( $register_form );

  ?>

</div>
```

My problem is that all the 3 forms are rendering in one more form tag.

**My Output:**

```
<form action="/drupal728/user" method="post" id="user-login">;
    <form>Registration....</form>
    <form>Password....</form>
    <form>Login</form>
</form>
```

I don't want that unwanted root form tag, how can I remove that one? I am using drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some theme-wrapper? Look in hook_registry_alter() if there is something else.

Also, Why do you add form in such strange way? If it is login form let it staying login form.
Better add additional forms near login form, you can append block or print form in page template.